# Как сделать чтобы <p> тег был внутри <div> в SQL

Tags: html, sql, база-данных, html5

Привет, мир!

Дорогие друзья, у меня есть такой вопрос, мне необходимо чтобы `<p>` тег был внутри `<div>` блока, чтобы сделать адаптивность, ньюанс в том, что код подгружается с SQL Базы данных, я там уже внес коррективы, однако не могу сделать так, чтобы `<p>`, находился внутри элемента,

К примеру должно быть так:

```
<div class="custom">
    <div class="yslygi">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src="/images/pencil.png" alt="" />
                    <p>Правильный замер</p>
                </div>
            </div>

         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Вот он исходный SQL код:

```
(94, 89, 'Мы предоставляем комплекс услуг', '', '<div class=\"yslygi\">\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div><img src=\"images/pencil.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>\r\n<div><img src=\"images/arrow.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>\r\n<div><img src=\"images/larry.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>\r\n<div><img src=\"images/arrow.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>\r\n<div><img src=\"images/tools.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>\r\n<div><img src=\"images/arrow.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>\r\n<div><img src=\"images/clock.png\" alt=\"\" /></div>\r\n</div>\r\n<div>\r\n<p>Правильный замер</p>\r\n<div> </div>\r\n<p>Доставка дверей</p>\r\n<div> </div>\r\n<p>Установка дверей</p>\r\n<div> </div>\r\n<p>Гарантия</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>', 1, 'right_top', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, 'mod_custom', 1, 1, '{\"prepare_content\":\"0\",\"backgroundimage\":\"\",\"layout\":\"_:default\",\"moduleclass_sfx\":\"\",\"cache\":\"1\",\"cache_time\":\"900\",\"cachemode\":\"static\",\"module_tag\":\"div\",\"bootstrap_size\":\"0\",\"header_tag\":\"div\",\"header_class\":\" modtit1\",\"style\":\"0\"}', 0, '*'),
```

А то получается, такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите тот hml-код, который в итоге приходит в браузер

Comment: Так, стоп, я чего-то не понимаю, или у вас действительно в самом SQL картинки и теги "p" в разных div-блоках?